# Batch script for loop with prefix

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've written a batch script which processes a series of files, but now I want it to copy the output files to the correct directory.

```
for %%f in (closecaption_*.txt) do (
  "%cd%\bin\captioncompiler.exe" "%cd%\%%f"
  copy /y "%cd%\%%f" "Z:\Users\jbzdarkid\"
)
pause
```

Currently, this script will copy all of the .txt files into my home directory. However, I want it to move the .dat files (the output) into my directory instead. Ideally, it would only move the new .dat files, i.e. the ones that have just been processed.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
for %%f.txt in (closecaption_*.txt) do (
  "%cd%\bin\captioncompiler.exe" "%cd%\%%f.txt"
  copy /y "%cd%\%%f.dat" "Z:\Users\jbzdarkid\"
)
pause
```

however this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%f in (closecaption_*.txt) do (
  "%cd%\bin\captioncompiler.exe" "%cd%\%%f"
  copy /y "%cd%\%%~nf.dat" "Z:\Users\jbzdarkid\"
)
pause
```

should work, if my crystal ball is working correctly. It selects the name-par of `%%f`.

Some examples would have made the matter clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%f in ('dir /a-d /b "%cd%\closecaption_*.txt"') do (
    "%cd%\bin\captioncompiler.exe" "%cd%\%%f"
    copy /y "%cd%\%%f.dat" "Z:\Users\jbzdarkid\"
)
pause
```